# python django как корретно заполнить в HTML таблицу из списка содержащего кортежи

Tags: html, django, table, tuple

Есть такой список состоящий из кортежей:

result = [(1, 'ivan', 36), (2, 'oleg', 31), (3, 'dima', 27)].

На выходе должна быть обычная table (HTML) 3 строки, 3 столбца

```
<table>
    <tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>age</th>
    </tr>
{% for user in users %}
   <td>{{ user.0 }}</td>
   <td>{{ user.1 }}</td>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: а что мешает тебе добавить третий `<td>...</td>`, так же как ты сделать для первых двух? Плюс ты забыл в цикле открыть <tr>, в который нужно поместить эти `<td>`

Comment: хорошо попробую, спасибо за направление :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
<table>
    <tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>age</th>
    </tr>

      {% for user in users %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ user.0 }}</td>
            <td>{{ user.1 }}</td>
            <td>{{ user.2 }}</td>
        </tr>
      {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: хорошо, учтю это в будущем )